# jQuery Get IP Address

Tags: jquery, ip-address, jsonp, jquery-load

Age old question. Need to find a solution.

This:

$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?", function(data){ip=data.ip});

Does not seem to work anymore:

```
App Engine Error

Over Quota

This Google App Engine application is temporarily over its serving quota. 
Please try again later.
```

I found this http://checkip.dyndns.org/

I used load (datatype set as jsonp) to attempt to get the html but I do not think I am doing it right or it just can not be done.

Any help?

Thanks a stack ;-)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The error you're getting when using the first application has nothing to do with your code: http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#quota

Comment: What about writing your own simple server-side "IP checker app" instead of using third parties? Here's one in PHP: `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>` :)

Answer (score 5):

Just create a php file with the following code:

> echo ' [ { "ip" : "$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']" }  ]';

and then ping that with get JSON

Comment: Yep, that is what i thought +1

Comment: Thank you for the response. Only have HTML to my disposal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Require jQuery / Anyversion --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Require EasyJQuery After JQuery --><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " \nCountry: " + json.Country);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {
        // more information at http://api.easyjquery.com/test/demo-ip.php
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " \nCountry: " + json.Country + " City: " + json.CityName + " RegionName: " + json.RegionName);
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
   // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback"); // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version
</script>



[IP] => 93.154.204.205
    [ContinentCode] => NA
    [ContinentName] => North America
    [CountryCode2] => US
    [CountryCode3] => USA
    [COUNTRY] => US
    [CountryName] => United States
    [RegionName] => California
    [CityName] => Garden Grove
    [CityLatitude] => 33.7831
    [CityLongitude] => -118.0271
    [CountryLatitude] => 38
    [CountryLongitude] => -98
    [LocalTimeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 77.93.210.64
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 
    [CallingCode] => 1
    [Population] => 307,212,123 (3)
    [AreaSqKm] => 9,826,675 (4)
    [GDP_USD] => 14.26 Trillion (1)
    [Capital] => Washington, D.C.
    [Electrical] => 120 V,60 Hz Type A Type B
    [Languages] => English 82.1%, Spanish 10.7%, other Indo-European 3.8%, Asian and Pacific island 2.7%, other 0.7% (2000 census)
    [Currency] => US Dollar (USD)
    [Flag] => http://api.easyjquery.com/proips/flags/US.jpg
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of what your code is doing along with your answer.